# Openlayers: cluster with different layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have multiple layers (WFS) to be chosen from a menu. I use Openlayers. Each layer has a different marker, as seen in the image below. However, I want to group the points, that is, use the clustering technique. I saw this example http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.animatedcluster.html. Below is code how I create each layer. How to adapt so that different layers are grouped, while keeping the marker of each one?

[EDIT CODE]
To test, even without the different markers for each layer, I got the code http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.animatedcluster.html. and I just changed the source for my data. Dont show nothing. Where is the error?

```
    // Layers
var layers = [ new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
})];

// The map
var map=new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    zoom: 12,
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-46.444137, -23.713596]), 
  }),
  layers: layers
});

// Style for the clusters
var styleCache = {};
function getStyle (feature, resolution){
  var size = feature.get('features').length;
  var style = styleCache[size];
  if (!style) {
    var color = size>25 ? "192,0,0" : size>8 ? "255,128,0" :"0,128,0";
    var radius = Math.max(8, Math.min(size*0.75, 20));
    var dash = 2*Math.PI*radius/6;
    var dash = [ 0, dash, dash, dash, dash, dash, dash ];
    style = styleCache[size] = new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: radius,
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: "rgba("+color+",0.5)", 
          width: 15 ,
          lineDash: dash,
          lineCap: "butt"
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color:"rgba("+color+",1)"
        })
      }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: size.toString(),
        //font: 'bold 12px comic sans ms',
        //textBaseline: 'top',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#fff'
        })
      })
    });
  }
  return style;
}

// Cluster Source
var clusterSource=new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 40,
  source:  new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
        return urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MY_LAYER&' +              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
            'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    })
});
// Animated cluster layer
var clusterLayer = new ol.layer.AnimatedCluster({
  name: 'Cluster',
  source: clusterSource,
  animationDuration: 700, 
  // Cluster style
  style: getStyle
});
map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
// add 2000 features
// Style for selection
var img = new ol.style.Circle({
  radius: 5,
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color:"rgba(0,255,255,1)", 
    width:1 
  }),
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color:"rgba(0,255,255,0.3)"
  })
});
var style0 = new ol.style.Style({
  image: img
});
var style1 = new ol.style.Style({
  image: img,
  // Draw a link beetween points (or not)
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color:"#fff", 
    width:1 
  }) 
});
// Select interaction to spread cluster out and select features
var selectCluster = new ol.interaction.SelectCluster({
  // Point radius: to calculate distance between the features
  pointRadius:7,
  // circleMaxObjects: 40,
  // spiral: false,
  // autoClose: false,
  animate: true, //$("#animatesel").prop('checked'),
  // Feature style when it springs apart
  featureStyle: style1,
  // selectCluster: false,  // disable cluster selection
  // Style to draw cluster when selected
  style: function(f,res){
    var cluster = f.get('features');
    if (cluster.length>1){
      var s = [ getStyle(f,res) ];
      return s;
    } else {
      return [
      new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle ({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "rgba(0,0,192,0.5)", width:2 }),
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: "rgba(0,0,192,0.3)" }),
          radius:5
        })
      })];
    }
  }
});
map.addInteraction(selectCluster);

// On selected => get feature in cluster and show info
selectCluster.getFeatures().on(['add'], function (e){
  var c = e.element.get('features');
  if (c.length==1){
    var feature = c[0];
    $(".infos").html("One feature selected...<br/>(id="+feature.get('NUM_CIE')+")");
  } else {
    $(".infos").text("Cluster ("+c.length+" features)");
  }
})
selectCluster.getFeatures().on(['remove'], function (e){
  $(".infos").html("");
})
```

[image]

[EDIT] I've posted the same question at different times, but I didn't get an answer. to help me develop what I need.

Come on, the image below refers to the map with Leaflet.
I have a layer menu/control (3) and I can choose as many as I want.
In the image (1) it shows the grouping with number 2, it refers to two points that are in the same place, from different layers.
In the image (3), we can see two different icons, each according to a layer.

That is, I can group all the layers in the same grouping and keep the characteristics each one (each has different information and icon).
Okay, this with Leaflet.

Now I need to do the same with Openlayers. My layers are configured in geoserver, they are WFS.
Any ideas, how to group different layers in the same grouping?
I tried using http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.animatedcluster.html but no I managed to do what I needed.
[image]

Comment: @Viglino Jean-Marc can you help me?

Comment: @Mike can you help me?

Comment: Can anyone help me? I've done it with leaflet, but I couldn't with openlayers and wfs layers