# Measure with tips: help delete

Tags: tooltip, openlayers, draw, measure

I'm using the example https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.tooltip.measure.html to measure area and line in openlayers.
I would like that, after making the drawing, I showed the measure and it doesn't erase.
Only delete when clicking a Delete button. Any tips on how to do it?
[image]

Comment: The ol-ext tooltip is designed to always move with the pointer.  You also need the Draw interactions to be linked to a vector source on the map for the features to be displaced after drawing is finished. Either of the OpenLayers examples https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html or https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html will do as you want, one using a standard Overlay, the other using vector styles for the output.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, I took these example codes, but it doesn't work in my application code. I don't know if I have some code that is interfering. I start to draw the line, but it doesn't finish. I'll see what I can do. Taking advantage, could you help me with my cluster question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511500/openlayers-cluster-with-different-layers