# Cluster in Openlayers with map.animatedcluster: style and cluster of layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, markerclusterer

I need to group the points to show on my map, with Openlayers.
I'm following the example http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.animatedcluster.html.

I was able to change it so that my layer is a WFS layer. In the following image, I have two layers, however, they do not group both together, but separately. In the part highlighted in red, we can see a green and an orange grouping very close together, each referring to a layer. How do I make clustering occur for all layers that are shown on the map?
[image]

I had already made a post a few months ago about this example [Openlayers: cluster with different layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511500/openlayers-cluster-with-different-layers)

Another thing, layer layer has a different style. I would like to keep this style, when the cluster is selected and/or when there is only one point in the cluster. Any tips?

[EDIT]

```
// Cluster Source
var clusterSource1=new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 60,
  source:  new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
        return urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MyLAYER1&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
            'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    })
});
// Animated cluster layer
var clusterLayer1 = new ol.layer.AnimatedCluster({
  name: 'Cluster1',
  source: clusterSource1,
  animationDuration: 700, 
  style: getStyle
});

var clusterSource2=new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 60,
  source:  new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
        return urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MyLAYER2&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
            'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    })
});


var clusterLayer2 = new ol.layer.AnimatedCluster({
  name: 'Cluster2',
  source:  clusterSource2,
  animationDuration: 700, 
  style: getStyle
});
map.addLayer(clusterLayer1);
map.addLayer(clusterLayer2);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have two separate cluster sources?

Comment: @BR75, That is, two source clusters, each referring to a layer. I gave the example with two layers, but they can be more.

Comment: You could try to combine both vector sources into another source, which could be the source for your cluster layer.

Comment: @BR75 I have a layer switch, where we can choose one or more layers to be shown on the map. Each one has a specific source. That way I could have a main source which is the combination of all the sources that have been tagged, is that it? But when deselecting a layer, is it possible to remove a source from the main source?
I had already used it in leaflet and it was very simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve this. You will have all the Features from different sources in one feature-collection. Each feature is being tagged, so you don't have different layers. You set a property to distinguish your features. If you want to remove a "layer", you just remove the feature from the source, if it's there else push it back. Hope this is what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/komarara/8jbzL019/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    .map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.11.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.11.0/css/ol.css">
</head>

<body>
  <Button onClick="handleVisibilityLayer1()">Layer1</Button>
  <Button onClick="handleVisibilityLayer2()">Layer2</Button>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    let source;
    let featureCollection = [];
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        drawMap();
    });
    
    function handleVisibilityLayer1(){
    
        for(const feature of featureCollection){
            const layerId = feature.get('layer');
            
            if(layerId === 'layer1' && source.hasFeature(feature)){
                source.removeFeature(feature);
            
            } else if(layerId === 'layer1' && !source.hasFeature(feature)){
                source.addFeature(feature);
            }
        }
    }
    
    function handleVisibilityLayer2(){
        for(const feature of featureCollection){
            const layerId = feature.get('layer');
            
            if(layerId === 'layer2' && source.hasFeature(feature)){
                source.removeFeature(feature);
            
            } else if(layerId === 'layer2' && !source.hasFeature(feature)){
                source.addFeature(feature);
            }
        }
    }

    function drawMap() {
        
    const feature1 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([818131.46, 5846162.87]),
        layer: 'layer1',
    });
    
    const feature2 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([818130.46, 5846162.87]),
        layer: 'layer1',
    });
    
    const feature11 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([818131.46, 5846161.87]),
        layer: 'layer2',
    });
    
    const feature22 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([818130.46, 5846161.87]),
        layer: 'layer2',
    });
    
    featureCollection = [feature1, feature2, feature11, feature22];
        
    source = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: featureCollection,
    });
        
    const clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
        source: source,
    });
        
    const styleCache = {};
    const clusterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: clusterSource,
      style: function (feature) {
        const size = feature.get('features').length;
        let style = styleCache[size];
        if (!style) {
          style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
              radius: 10,
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#fff',
              }),
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#3399CC',
              }),
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
              text: size.toString(),
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#fff',
              }),
            }),
          });
          styleCache[size] = style;
        }
        return style;
      },
    });
    
    const osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({
            attributions: '© OpenStreetMap',
        })
    });
      
    map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            osmLayer,
            clusterLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View(),
    });

    map.getView().fit(source.getExtent());
    
    }
        
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still going to test it, but I still have some doubts.
In this case, I have a layers menu where one or more layers can be marked. In this case, each layer has a source. Instead of calling layer1, for example, should I call a function, as you did with the button click? When this layer is added, other functionality is performed as well.   `var overlays = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Layers',
 fold: 'open',
        layers: [layer1,
  layer2,]
});
map.addLayer(overlays)`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. So you want to keep your layer. These layers are all Point Layer, right? And now you want to cluster the points from every layer. So you want to turn your cluster layer on and off and if it's on all the other features should disappear right? Because otherwise you will end up with redundant points.

Comment: I have several layers and you can check/uncheck as many as you want to show the information on the map.
However, I would like this information (marked layers) to show grouped on the map, as
multiple pieces of information can be at the same location or close together. I've done it with Leaflet in a very simple way, however, I'm not getting it with Openlayers.
This is the Portal working, with Leaflet [link](https://siga.santoandre.sp.gov.br/siga/index.php)

Comment: Link does not work for me... So you want your regular layer AND the cluster layer with all features from all regular layer you have at the same time? And if you set the visibility of one regular layer off, you want the features to disappear in the cluster layer also, right?

Comment: I wrote as an answer, to explain the doubts showing the images

Answer (score 0):

I have several layers and I can choose one or more to show on the map. In the picture, I am twice,
each with a different tag.

Each layer has a corresponding source, which is a WFS.

```
var layer 1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      //code })
 })
```

When you click on any point, it shows a popup with the specific layer information.

[image]
What I want? Group this information to avoid polluting the map. I already developed with Leaflet, but I'm not
with Openlayers.
In Brochure I used L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport

[image]
I started a test, following the code http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.animatedcluster.html.
and I even posted my initial test code, but it didn't group data from different layers, I didn't give sequential
in upcoming changes.

[EDIT]
How to add features from one source to another? Is not working

```
    // Cluster Source
var clusterSource_=new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 40,
    source: new ol.source.Vector()
});
// Animated cluster layer
var clusterLayer_ = new ol.layer.AnimatedCluster(
{   name: 'Cluster',
    source: clusterSource_,
    style: getStyle
});
map.addLayer(clusterLayer_);


var teste =  new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
        return urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:MYLAYER1&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
            'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
})
var features = teste.getFeatures();
alert(features.length); //this alerts '0', but there's more than 10 features!!


clusterSource_.getSource().clear();
clusterSource_.getSource().addFeatures(teste.getSource().getFeatures());
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with leaflet but why not just use leaflet then? I don't know other way than have one source and manage the rest by myself. You should be fine to have an additional source and layer for clustering. You can add an event listener to your current layer, if the visibility change just add / remove specific features to the cluster source. You can style almost everything like you want, just check the official examples on openlayers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do more research and see what I can find. We already have a Portal with Leaflet working, however, we are in a migration and one of the changes is the use of Openlayers, which worked better with Geoserver. So I'm redoing everything that already worked and I have several doubts. Considering that my source is WFS data, how do I add features from one source to another?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have WFS, it's about the Features. You can push and remove them from the cluster source, like in the Solution I posted. You can also check out this example to see what's possible with custom styling: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/clusters-dynamic.html

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations and patience. But, I'm not able to get the features of a source and add in another. I even put an alert, but it shows 0 features.
I edited the question to show the code.

Comment: Probably not loaded yet, there is an event: wfsSource.on('featuresloadend', (vectorSourceEvent) => {
   console.log('features from wfs', vectorSourceEvent.features?.length);
  })

Comment: Btw. I would not work with the cluster source directly, instead work with intermediate source you pass to the cluster source, like in my example.

Comment: I followed the example of the event wfsSource.on('featuresloadend', (vectorSourceEvent) => { console.log('features from wfs', vectorSourceEvent.features?.length); }) and it shows the amount of attributes correctly, however, this event only worked if the layer associated with ess wfsSource is added to the map; In this case, it is duplicating, as I add the layer and then the cluster layer. Any suggestion?

Comment: check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Layer with only one Cluster-Source/Layer. I'm just pushing all features to one array. However, this is just a proof of concept, at a certain amount of features, you will get performance issues, so there is room for improvement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    .map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.13.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.13.0/css/ol.css"> 
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" onChange="handleLayerVisibility('layer1', this.checked)">Layer1</input>
  <input type="checkbox" onChange="handleLayerVisibility('layer2', this.checked)">Layer2</Checkbox>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    let intermediateClusterSource;

    const feature1 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([818131.46, 5846162.87]),
        layer: 'layer2'
    });
    const feature2 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([818130.46, 5846162.87]),
        layer: 'layer2'
    });
    const feature3 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([818131.46, 5846161.87]),
        layer: 'layer2'
    });
    const feature4 = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([818130.46, 5846161.87]),
        layer: 'layer2'
    });
    
    const featureCollection = [feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4];
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        drawMap();
    });
    
    function handleLayerVisibility(layerId, checked){
        for(const feature of featureCollection){
            const id = feature.get('layer');
            if(id !== layerId){
                continue;
            }
            if(checked){
                intermediateClusterSource.addFeature(feature);
            } else {
                intermediateClusterSource.removeFeature(feature);
            }
        }
    }
    
    function drawMap() {
    
        const source1 = new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            loader: function(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
                     var proj = projection.getCode();
                     var url = 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                         'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=osm:water_areas&' +
                         'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=' + proj;
                         
                     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                     xhr.open('GET', url);
                     var onError = function() {
                       source1.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
                       failure();
                     }
                     xhr.onerror = onError;
                     xhr.onload = function() {
                       if (xhr.status == 200) {
                         var features = source1.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText);
                         for(const [index, feature] of features.entries()){
                            const geometry = feature.getGeometry();
                            if(geometry instanceof ol.geom.SimpleGeometry){
                                if(index < 100){
                                    const coords = geometry.getCoordinates()[0][0][0];
                                    if(coords && coords.length === 2){
                                        const feat = new ol.Feature({
                                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coords),
                                            layer: 'layer1'
                                        });
                                        featureCollection.push(feat);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                         }
                         
                         success(features);
                       } else {
                         onError();
                       }
                     }
                     xhr.send();
            },
        });

        const layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
            id: 'layer1',
            source: source1,
        })
        
        const source2 = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4]
        })
        
        const layer2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
            id: 'layer2',
            source: source2,
            visible: false,
        })
        
        intermediateClusterSource = new ol.source.Vector();
            
        const clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
            source: intermediateClusterSource,
        });
            
        const styleCache = {};
        const clusterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: clusterSource,
          style: function (feature) {
            const size = feature.get('features').length;
            let style = styleCache[size];
            if (!style) {
              style = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                  radius: 10,
                  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#fff',
                  }),
                  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#3399CC',
                  }),
                }),
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                  text: size.toString(),
                  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#fff',
                  }),
                }),
              });
              styleCache[size] = style;
            }
            return style;
          },
        });
        
        const osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                attributions: '© OpenStreetMap',
            })
        });
          
        map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                osmLayer,
                layer1,
                layer2,
                clusterLayer
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                zoom: 1,
                center: [0,0],
            }),
        });
    }
     
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I followed your code, but the check layer 1 doesn't show anything. It's the same problem I'm having, I'm not able to get the ws layer geometries. Does geometry, a pattern of how it should be? Use Oracle database.

Comment: If you could post that code I could check what’s wrong

Comment: Use this same code to test. When I click on layer2, ok, it shows the 4 points grouped. But on layer1 (geoserver layer), it doesn't show anything). What I did was just change the url to my geoserver, but that doesn't work either. In that line 
`const coords = geometry.getCoordinates()[0][0][0]; `returns null, so I left it as `const coords = geometry.getCoordinates()`
 And it doesn't enter this if either, because leggth is 1 `if(coords && coords.length === 2){`

Comment: As for the projection, in the geoserver my layer is like EPSG:4326

Comment: Actually what I need is to group points from different layers. I can choose several layers and show them all grouped and not group by layer. I tried using http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.animatedcluster.html but I didn't get the desired result either.